# If the $E$ component of an EM wave interacts with another $B$ field (from other source), can they generate Poyting vector (or photon flux)?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, interference, superposition, poynting-vector

[image]

As shown in the figure, a planar EM wave propagates in the $z$-direction, and its electric component is in the $x$-direction. Meanwhile, in the whole region, there is a static magnetic field B everywhere, so, can the fluctuating E component of this planar EM wave, interact with such static magnetic field B, to generate the Poyting vector in $y$-direction, e.g. as shown at the point A? If so, can we detect the photons of such Poyting vector, and is there any experiment that had addressed similar cases please?

Answer (score 0):

The solutions to Maxwell's equations obey the principle of superposition. So of course you can have an electromagnetic wave *and* a static B-field in the same place.

The addition of a static B field gives an extra component to the Poynting vector. That component is in the y-direction in your diagram. It fluctuates sinusoidally, has a time-average of zero, and therefore does not transport any energy and there is no net flux.

Comment: All of this us correct but such results were flagged as counterintuitive in Panofsky and Phillips. I subscribe to their view.

Comment: @my2cts The Poynting vector is *defined* to be $\vec{E}\times \vec{H}$, I don't understand the point you are making.

Comment: In the case of static fields the Poynting vector gives nonzero momentum density. This is brought up as a reason to interpret to Poynting vector with caution in the textbook of Panofsky and Phillips. I agree with this warning.

Comment: @RobJeffries   Thank you!  I understand that the time-average of the Poynting vector at the point A, should be zero, due to its direction fluctuates in the Y-direction, but, if we measure such Poyting vector by some sensor which responses to only one direction, e.g., only detect the photon flux in the positive Y-direction (but not reponse to the photon flux in the minus Y-direction), then, should such detector catch the photons of such Poyting vector please?